# Difficulty with creating Syntax Trees (d and s structure)?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

Can someone please help with drawing the following tree in s-structure.
"Which fat pig did the small sheet bite behind the barn?"
How would I do so if you are suppressing the structures of all specifiers and all adjuncts in triangles?

I'm utterly confused by building syntactic trees and cannot find enough examples in the book I have to help.

I am also having trouble with drawing the tree for "the deputy's recent discovery of incriminating evidence"  while putting all specifics, all complements, and all adjuncts in triangles.

Comment: Ask your teacher. They're the only ones who know what they want you to do. If you don't understand the structure already, it's not helpful to worry about jots and tittles.

Comment: I agree with the comment. The notions of d- and s-structure are outdated, and furthermore, the particular structural analysis is subject to the whim of the trend and/or syntactician at hand.

Comment: @jlawler If you don't think this is a good question for the site, you should vote to close it. We should probably come to some sort of consensus on these homework type questions.

Comment: All syntactic theory is outdated, practically speaking. It changes too fast for anyone to keep up, and will keep on doing so.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 2 years old, but I thought this might help someone else with a similar struggle!

S-structure with triangles for "Which fat pig did the small sheet bite behind the barn?":

[image: S-structure]

for reference, here's the D-structure (without triangles):

[image: D-structure]